# how to use my own option in my bash script function

Tags: bash

i have a little function i use to quickly open up a search in chrome (used to be firefox, there for "ff").
i'd like to add the option `-u` so i can go to a page instead of searching.

currently the option seems to be used by "open" here in my code, but i want it to be my option. what am i doing wrong here?

```sh
function ff() {
    if [ $1 = "-u" ]; then
        open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" "$*"
    else 
        open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" "http://google.com/search?q=$*"
    fi
}
```

usage:

works:
`$ ff my search string`

doesn't work: `$ ff -u www.example.com`

Comment: Add an example of the invocation please.

Comment: Look into getopts: do `help getopts` and `man bash`.

Comment: It should be `open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" "$2"` I think.

Comment: or `shift ; open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" "$*"` The `-u` is still in `"$*"` until you `shift` it away. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1 should be quoted inside if condition to avoid "too many arguments" error and argument to your option should be $2.
Also, always quote arguments to protect spaces: `"my search string"`.

```
function ff() {
    if [ "$1" = "-u" ]; then
        firefox "$2"
    else
        firefox "http://google.com/search?q=$*"
    fi
}

ff -u "www.example.com"
#ff "bash getopts"
```

Comment: tnx! i'll be using this.

Answer (score 1):

Example of script using getopts, a bash builtin:

```
#!/bin/bash

my_option=0
while getopts "u" opt
do
    case "$opt" in
        u) my_option=1 ;;
        *) ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

if [ "$my_option" -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "no option"
    echo "$@"
else
    echo "my option used!"
    echo "$@"
fi

$> script foo bar
no option
foo bar

$> script -u foo bar
my option used!
foo bar
```

Comment: tnx! i'll be looking into this sooner.